# Videos in other hard-disk then website root directory

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

I have my video content delivery website.

I have several Hard-disk having videos in it. I am working with IIS. I have my website in wwwroot directory in IIS.

Now I want users to access my videos from my site. But the videos are in other harddisk. How can I add a link in my website so that users can access the videos.

If the video is in the same wwwroot dir then it works very well.

Comment: Is this ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, ... ? Please edit question tags accordingly. And remove `content-delivery-network` (meaningless in this context), also remove `website` (too vague, the tag even says so: "DO NOT USE. Select some more descriptive tags, like html, css, php, http, etc.")

Comment: First make your hardisk video files path reachable for your IIS Web Server, after that  you can access your video using the web server route to your video files.

Comment: That is the thing i dont know how to do in IIS web server. @hokusai

Comment: You should to use something like `alias` in Apache web server. Maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431377/how-to-create-an-alias-path-on-local-iis